# Best approach of mysql query: Get records from multiple tables, using an id

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, query-performance

What is the most efficient way to get records from 3 tables, using an id that exists in all tables to link the data?

- First table: id is NOT a primary key. Many records have the same id value. This table's primary key is "primary_id"
- Second table: id is Primary key
- Third table: id is Primary key

So we have a relation Many-to-one from First table to the other two tables on "id". And of course second to third table has a relation one-to-one on "id", as "id" is primary key on both of them.

I want to select 5 records from first table (lets say order by first tables **primary_id**  asc - **not** the shared across tables **id**) but i want also the records from the other two tables.

I should get

```
table1.primary_id | table1.id | table1.some_data | table2.some_data | table3.some_data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                1 |        22 |          oranges |     fruit seller |          company
                4 |        22 |      watermelons |     fruit seller |          company
               13 |        22 |          bananas |     fruit seller |          company
               15 |        22 |            pears |     fruit seller |          company
               19 |        22 |            beans |     fruit seller |          company
```

as you can understand, in table2, where id is primary key, id=22 has some_data=fruit seller, and in table3 where id is primary key, id=22 has some_data=company

What should i use to get first 5 records by primary_id of table 1 and get also the records from the other two tables like i demonstrate?

A Join? A subquery? My concern is about **performance**.

Comment: ```JOIN```s have usually the better performance.

Comment: Do you have an index on `table1.id`?

Comment: @MarkBannister i can create as many indexes as i want, as INSERTS are rare. yes there can be an index. and any other index. specifically yes i have already indexed table1.id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select t1.primary_id, t1.id, t1.some_data, t2.some_data, t3.some_data
from table2 t2
join table3 t3 on t2.id = t3.id
cross join (select * from table1 where id = 22 order by primary_id limit 5) t1
where t2.id = 22
```

Ensure that there is an index on table1.id; the query *may* perform better if there is an index on id, primary_id (in that order).

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm creating some test data and testing